# Change all xamarin forms button background inside a listview

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have ListView with buttons inside.When button is clicked I need some way to change the background color of all other buttons exept the clicked button.
Initially all buttons inside my listview have a white background, when a button is clicked i check is background color is white then change to gray color and need to change background colors to white for all other buttons.
***This is the code:***

```
<control:ListViewNestedScroll
                    x:Name="ClassLevelListView"
                        HasUnevenRows="True"
                        RowHeight="30"
                        SeparatorVisibility="None"
                        IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                        IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRunning, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadClassLevelsCommand}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ClassLevels}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <control:CustomViewCell SelectedBackgroundColor="{StaticResource GreyColor}">
                                    <StackLayout Margin="0,0,0,10">
                                        <control:CustomButton
                                            Text="{Binding KeyName, Converter={StaticResource I18N}}"
                                            CornerRadius="20"
                                            BorderColor="Black"
                                            BorderWidth="2"
                                            TextColor="Black"
                                            BackgroundColor="White"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                            Clicked="Button_OnClicked" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </control:CustomViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </control:ListViewNestedScroll>


private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var classLevelButton = (Button)sender;
            var classLevel = classLevelButton.CommandParameter as ClassLevelModel;
            if (classLevelButton.BackgroundColor == Color.White)
            {
                classLevelButton.BackgroundColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["GreyColor"];
                ((RegisterTeacherClassLevelViewModel)BindingContext).AddTeacherClassLevel(classLevel);
            }
            else
            {
                classLevelButton.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
                ((RegisterTeacherClassLevelViewModel)BindingContext).RemoveTeacherClassLevel(classLevel);
            }
        }
```

Comment: you need to bind your Button's BG color to a property on your model, and then update your models when a button is clicked, which will cause the UI to update

Comment: Thanks Jason I did it but for some reason the UI is not updated. My viewmodel handle PropertyChangedEventArgs.I ended up after model change remove the entire list and create it again.Thanks for your help.